# how to get my current session usage in codeigniter

Tags: session, codeigniter, php

hi i am using `codeigniter` .

i know the `size` of `session` is `4kb`.

i want to get the `current` session usage in my site ,

i am looking for a function like like `get_session_current_usage()` (this is created by me ;))

instead of `Saving Session Data to a Database` . i would like to get my current session usage and if it is near 4kb , i want to destroy it . please help.................

Comment: define session usage? session size in kb? UPDATE: nevermind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you store the session in a plain cookie, the classic way of codeigniter just read the raw cookie and check the length of the cookie:

```
$cookie = $_COOKIE['your_session_name'];
$cookieSize = strlen($cookie);
if($cookieSize > $CookieSizeLimit) {
    // do something
}
```

Why do you want to destroy the cookie after a set size? just curious